# How to load txt on array pointers in c

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, segment

Hey i would like some help on this i am trying to load a dictionary on my c programm but i take segment fault. I would love some help.
while debuging with gdb it says that it failed on line 63 which the command says : `lines[i]=string_coppied`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

const int step=200;
char **loadfile();


int main()
{   
  char **words=loadfile();
  if (words==NULL) printf ("cant build structure");
  for (int i=0 ; i<100 ; i++) printf("%s \n" , words[i] );
}

char **loadfile()
{
  //We load our text file at the stack
  FILE * fpointer;
  fpointer = fopen ("word.txt" , "r");
  if (fpointer==NULL) printf ("file not loaded \n");
  else printf ("File loaded \n");

  int array_size=step;
  char ** lines=(char **)malloc(array_size*sizeof(char*));
  if (lines=NULL) printf ("cant allocate memory \n");

  char temp[100];
  int i=0;

  while (fgets(temp,100,fpointer))
  {
    //we check if the already allocated memory is full , if so we realloc
    if (i==array_size)
    { 
      array_size +=step;

      char **newlines= (char**)realloc(lines , array_size * sizeof(char*));
      if (newlines==NULL) //check if the memory was allocated
      {
         printf ("Cant reallocate memory , please try again \n ");
         return 0 ;
      }

      lines=newlines;
    }
    //now that we made sure that the memory was allocated we continue by copying the temp //
    temp[strlen(temp)-1]="\0" ;
    int length =strlen(temp);
    char * string_coppied=malloc((length+1) * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(string_coppied ,temp);
    lines[i]=string_coppied;
    i++;
  }
  return lines;

  free(lines);
  fclose(fpointer);
}
```

Comment: you already accepted my answer, but I edited my answer to add a proposal for your program

Comment: i tried to modify my programm with the notes you made but i was still getting core dumped while your proposal is working perfectly i will study yours and try to understand my mistakes. Sry i am inexperienced

Comment: it is possible I missed something in your program, I just looked at it without trying to modify and make it running ;-) If you can use _valgrind_ run your program under it to check the memory accesses and more, _valgrind_ is a fantastic tool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> gdb it says that it failed on line 63 which the command says : `lines[i]=string_coppied`

this is because after

> ```
> char **newlines= (char**)realloc(lines , array_size * sizeof(char*));
> ```

you cannot use *lines* after the *realloc* because if is potentially freed by *realloc*, and visibly this is what happened because gdb signals the problem

---

But you have more problems in your code

1) the compiler signal an error on the line `temp[strlen(temp)-1]="\0" ;` because *temp* is an array of *char*, not an array of *char**, you certainly wanted `temp[strlen(temp)-1] = 0 ;`

2) in *main* :

> ```
>  if (words==NULL) printf ("cant build structure");
>  for (int i=0 ; i<100 ; i++) printf("%s \n" , words[i] );
> ```

an *else* is missing, if *worlds* is *NULL* you do the *for* and (try to) access to `words[i]` with an undefined behavior

3) in *main*

> ```
> for (int i=0 ; i<100 ; i++) printf("%s \n" , words[i] );
> ```

you access to the 100 first entries of *words* to print them without knowing its size/how many entries it has, if it has are less than 100 entries you have an other undefined behavior, if it has more you do not print all of them

*loadfile* must return the number of entries, for instance through an output variable `char **loadfile(size_t * n)` allowing you to do `for (int i=0 ; i<n ; i++) ...`

4) in *loadfile*

> ```
>  fpointer = fopen ("word.txt" , "r");
>  if (fpointer==NULL) printf ("file not loaded \n");
>  else printf ("File loaded \n");
> ```

if you cannot open file file you print a message *and you continue the execution*, you need to `return NULL;`

Note you are also optimistic because you already print `File loaded` while you just open the file

5) in *loadfile*

> ```
>  char ** lines=(char **)malloc(array_size*sizeof(char*));
>  if (lines=NULL) printf ("cant allocate memory \n");
> ```

if *malloc* returns *NULL* you print the message *and you continue the execution*, so you can do later `lines[i]=string_coppied;` while *lines* is *NULL* with an undefined behavior

6) in *loadfile*

As I said

> ```
>  char **newlines= (char**)realloc(lines , array_size * sizeof(char*));
>  if (newlines==NULL) //check if the memory was allocated
>  {
>      printf ("Cant reallocate memory , please try again \n ");
>      return 0 ;
>  }
>
>  lines=newlines;
> ```

can be replaced by

```
  lines= (char**)realloc(lines , array_size * sizeof(char*));
  if (lines==NULL) //check if the memory was allocated
  {
      printf ("Cant reallocate memory , please try again \n ");
      return NULL;
  }
```

7) in *loadfile*

when doing (I changed "\0" to 0) :

> ```
> temp[strlen(temp)-1]=0;
> int length =strlen(temp);
> ```

you compute 2 times the length of the string while you know the second *strlen* values the first minus 1, do

```
int length = strlen(temp) - 1;

temp[length] = 0;
```

but there is an other problem, you do that to remove the newline, but

- the last line of the file may not contain a new line and you lost the last character in that case.
- when a line is greater than 100 characters it is cut on several, and the first sub lines do not contain a newline and you remove their last character

To not cut the lines, and to not have to duplicate them too, you can use *getline*

8) in *loadfile*

In

> ```
> return lines;
>
> free(lines);
> fclose(fpointer);
> ```

the last two lines cannot be executed so you do not free *lines* (but that is better because you return it) and the file is not closed

---

A proposal :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

const int step=200;
char **loadfile(ssize_t * n);

int main()
{   
  ssize_t n;
  char **words=loadfile(&n);

  if (words == NULL)
    puts("error when reading file");
  else {
    for (ssize_t i = 0 ; i < n ; i++) {
      puts(words[i]);
      free(words[i]);
    }
  }
}

char **loadfile(ssize_t * n)
{
  *n = 0;

  //We load our text file at the stack
  FILE * fpointer = fopen ("word.txt" , "r");

  if (fpointer==NULL) {
    printf ("file not loaded \n");
    return NULL;
  }
  puts ("load file");

  int array_size = 0;
  char ** lines = NULL;

  for (;;) {
    char * lineptr = NULL;
    size_t zero = 0;
    ssize_t sz = getline(&lineptr, &zero, fpointer);

    if (sz <= 0) {
      fclose(fpointer);
      return lines;
    }

    if (lineptr[sz - 1] == '\n')
      lineptr[sz - 1] = 0;

    if (*n == array_size)
    { 
      array_size += step;
      lines = realloc(lines , array_size * sizeof(char*));

      if (lines == NULL) //check if the memory was allocated
      {
         printf ("Cant reallocate memory , please try again \n ");
         return NULL;
      }
    }

    lines[*n] = lineptr;
    *n += 1;
  }
}
```